# String mutation in array elements

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

I would like to manipulate array elements. So if a certain array element ends with the letter `n` or `m` and the following element is for example `apple` then I want to delete the "a" of "apple" so that I get as an output: `Array ( [0] => man [1] => pple )`

My Code:

```
$input = array("man","apple");

$ending = array("m","n");

$example = array("apple","orange");


for($i=0;$i<count($input);$i++)
{
   $second = isset( $input[$i+1])?$input[$i+1][0]:null;


   $third = substr($input[$i],-2);




        if( isset($third) && isset($second) ){
                    if (   in_array($third,$ending) && in_array($second,$example) ){
                    $input[$i+1] = substr($input[$i+1],0,-2);
                    }

        }   



}
```

How do I have to change my code so that I get the desired output?

Comment: So what would be the output if the array is like this: `array("man", "ham", "apple");`, would it be `array("man", "am", "pple");` ?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul   no, it would be the same as the output

Comment: So what's the logic behind this? `man` ends with `n`, so starting letter `h` of `ham` gets deleted. Likewise, now, `am` ends with letter `m`, hence letter `a` of `apple` gets deleted, leaving it as `pple`, isn't it? Please clarify the logic in the question.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul only and really only if the ending letter of a word is `n`and the next word is `apple` or `orange` then the first letter of those two words gets deleted. Logic is not important...it is just a simple case to understand it...

Comment: @MoeJoe you can check out my solution for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cool exercise task.

My approach to this after reading the starting comments would be something like this:

```
$input = ['man', 'hamster', 'apple', 'ham', 'red'];
$endings = ['m', 'n'];

$shouldRemove = false;
foreach ($input as $key => $word) {
    // if this variable is true, it will remove the first character of the current word.
    if ($shouldRemove === true) {
        $input[$key] = substr($word, 1);
    }

    // we reset the flag 
    $shouldRemove = false;
    // getting the last character from current word
    $lastCharacterForCurrentWord = $word[strlen($word) - 1];

    if (in_array($lastCharacterForCurrentWord, $endings)) {
        // if the last character of the word is one of the flagged characters,
        // we set the flag to true, so that in the next word, we will remove 
        // the first character.
        $shouldRemove = true;
    }
}

var_dump($input);
die();
```

The output of this script would be

`array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "man" [1]=> string(6) "amster" [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> string(3) "ham" [4]=> string(2) "ed" }`

I hope the explanation with the comments is enough.

Comment: not always if a word ends with a certain letter the next first letter will be removed. Only if the next word is `apple` or `orange`.